# how to incorporate perl modules into script

Tags: perl, perl-module, cpan

I am a beginner at Perl, I need to use functions from the Perl module Date::Easter in order to create a program that will take a year from user input and display the date of Easter within that year, i need to know how you would incorporate that module into the script in order to get the desired outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple enough:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Date::Easter;

chomp (my $year = <STDIN>);
my ($m1, $d1) = easter ($year);
my ($m2, $d2) = julian_easter ($year);
my ($m3, $d3) = orthodox_easter ($year);

print "Gregorian => Month: $m1 Day: $d1\n";
print "Julian    => Month: $m2 Day: $d2\n";
print "Orthodox  => Month: $m3 Day: $d3\n";
```

Comment: That was really helpful. That is according to the Gregorian, how would you do Julian and orthodox?

Comment: @user218001 Browse around here: https://metacpan.org/module/Date::Easter. It is pretty much the same method, just a different name.

Comment: but how would you put all 3 in the same script, so its prints 3 dates, one for Gregorian, one for Julian, and one for orthodox.

Comment: I need one more solution, i have been searching for a way to change the months from printing as numbers to actual spelled months, do i have to import some other module or is there a simpler way of achieving that.

Comment: @user218001 Looks like you asked that elsewhere!